# Is it possible to auto infer result types in Slick?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, play-slick

Let's say that I have this method that runs a fairly basic query using Slick's plain SQL:

```
object Data {

    case class User(user: String, password: String)

    implicit val getUserResult = GetResult(r => User(r.<<, r.<<))

    def getUser(user: String, password: String): Option[User] = DB.withSession {
        sql"""
            SELECT  "user", 
                    "password" 
            FROM    "user" 
            WHERE   "user" = $user AND 
                    "password" = $password
        """.as[User].firstOption
    }

}
```

What if I have a different query from the same table that has over 100 columns:

```
SELECT * FROM "user"
```

In this case there would be a whole lot of typing concerning these two lines:

```
case class User(user: String, password: String, something: Int, ...)
implicit val getUserResult = GetResult(r => User(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, ...))
```

Is it possible to somehow automate these two lines without manually mapping 100 columns? Auto inferring types or even if every column is returned as a string type would be a good alternative.

If specifics are required, my stack is Play Framework 2.2.1, Scala 2.10.3, Java 8 64Bit, PostgreSQL 9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you give to `GetResult` receives a [PositionedResult](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/api/index.html#scala.slick.session.PositionedResult) as its argument. Work with it as you like.

If you define

```
implicit val getListStringResult = scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult[List[String]](
  prs => (1 to prs.numColumns).map(_ => prs.nextString).toList
)
```

you can then say

```
sql"...".as[List[String]].firstOption
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but would it be possible to have result as a map of `column name -> value` pairs instead of just a plain list?

Comment: I mean something like `Map[String, String]` instead of `List[String]`.

Comment: answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891881/scala-slick-plain-sql-retrieve-result-as-a-map/19892330