# How to send results of a Scala StaticQuery SELECT query direct to JSON object

Tags: mysql, json, scala, playframework, slick

In Scala how can I most directly send the results of a MySql query to a JSON string?  We're working within the "play" framework and are using "slick" to connect to MySQL, so I'm more specifically trying to results of a [slick's StaticQuery](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1-RC1/sql.html) SELECT directly to a [play JsValue](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/ScalaJson) object.  However any solution to the general problem is welcome.

The select parameters of the query string are inserted dynamically and they have known MySQL types, but I don't generally know the specific parameters or the number of them at compile time.

I've got a feeling that there's a clever way to do this with case classes and Map objects, but I'm hoping that someone has already solved this problem more simply.  For example there is this related [Java Gist](https://gist.github.com/kdonald/2137988).

For example I currently have:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery => Q}

...

case class SrResult(id: Int, user_id: Int, title: String)
implicit val getSrResult = GetResult(r => SrResult(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<))

val qSql = "SELECT id,user_id,title from MYTABLE LIMIT 10"
val q = Q.queryNA[SrResult](qSql)
```

I will be inserting the "is,user_id,title" into the qSql string dynamically, so Q.queryNA's return type "SrResult" is not known at complile time.

For completeness here is an example table that I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE `MYTABLE` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TITLE` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` text
  `ARCHIVED` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_AT` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `END_DATE` date NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `TEST_USER_INDEX` (`USER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `TEST_USER_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `USERS` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1058 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up working at the lower JDBC level parsing the [ResultSet from an executeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) through [Play's Json tools](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/ScalaJson).  For example:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import utils.DatabaseConfig.driver.simple._
import slick.session.Database.threadLocalSession
import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager, ResultSet};
import java.util.Date

...

val rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS")

jsValueResult = sqlResultSetToJson(rs)
```

where

```
def sqlResultSetToJson(rs: ResultSet): JsValue = {
  // This is loosely ported from https://gist.github.com/kdonald/2137988

  val rsmd = rs.getMetaData
  val columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount

  // It may be faster to collect each line into a Seq or other iterable
  // and pass that to Json.arr() at the end.
  var qJsonArray: JsArray = Json.arr()
  while (rs.next) {
    var index = 1

    var rsJson: JsObject = Json.obj()
    while (index <= columnCount) {
      // Unfortunately jdbc ResultSetMetaData doesn't expose a reliable
      // getTableName method.  It returns the "originalTableName" which doesn't
      // include table aliases defined in the SELECT statement.
      // Therefore the table name needs to be hard coded into each column
      // name in the SELECT command.
      //
      // We should also be checking that there are no duplicate columnLabel's
      // The Json constructors will just mindlessly append items with dup names
      // to the JsObject.
      val column = rsmd.getColumnLabel(index)
      val columnLabel = column.toLowerCase()

      val value = rs.getObject(column)
      if (value == null) {
        rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
          columnLabel -> JsNull
        )
      } else if (value.isInstanceOf[Integer]) {
        println(value.asInstanceOf[Integer])
        rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
          columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[Int]
        )
      } else if (value.isInstanceOf[String]) {
        println(value.asInstanceOf[String])
        rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
          columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[String]
        )
      } else if (value.isInstanceOf[Boolean]) {
        rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
          columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[Boolean]
        )
      } else if (value.isInstanceOf[Date]) {
        rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
          columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[Date].getTime
        )
      } else if (value.isInstanceOf[Long]) {
        rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
          columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[Long]
        )
      } else if (value.isInstanceOf[Double]) {
        rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
          columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[Double]
        )
      } else if (value.isInstanceOf[Float]) {
        rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
          columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[Float]
        )
      } else if (value.isInstanceOf[BigDecimal]) {
        rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
          columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[BigDecimal]
        )
      // } else if (value.isInstanceOf[Byte]) {
      //   rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
      //     columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[Byte]
      //   )
      // } else if (value.isInstanceOf[Array[Byte]]) {
      //   rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
      //     columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]]
      //   )
      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unmappable object type: " + value.getClass)
      }
      index += 1
    }
    qJsonArray = qJsonArray :+ rsJson
  }
  qJsonArray
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It works for me. My question is, should we always check all `isInstanceOf`?

Answer (score 1):

I explain in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891881/scala-slick-plain-sql-retrieve-result-as-a-map/19892330#19892330) how to get a Map out of a Slick plain SQL query. You will need to adapt it to restrict it to only the fields you need. From the Map it should be trivial to get a JSON object with your favorite JSON library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One of challenges of my situation was that I needed to capture the implicit JSON types of the values, not just their String representations.